# Xamarin - disconnected from layout renderer

Tags: android, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

I just downloaded xamarin studio.  I get an error message "disconnected from layout renderer  please close the file and try again" whenever i open a axml in the layout folder.  I can view the source but can't go to the design tab to add controls.  Closing the filed does not work.

I'm not sure how to find what version of xamarin.android i'm using but I just downloaded last night.   When I go to the SDK manager it tells me my Android SDK Tools are version 23.0.4.

I found this old thread on the same topic.  I tried renaming my tools folder and downgrading but that didnt' work either.  It told me I need tools of at least version 22.

http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/14344/disconnected-from-layout-renderer-error-after-updating-android-sdk-tools-to-version-22-6

I've tried uninstalling Xamarin Studio and reinstalling and that didn't help.  I do have Visual Studio 2013 with update 3 installed too.  But then I also tried installing Xamarin Studio on another laptop with Visual Studio 2012 and got the exact same problem.

Note:  this error displays in both Visual Studio and Xamarin Studio.

I really hope I can get this resolved as i'm evaluating Xamarin for 2 companies.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

-Randy

Comment: For the record, I just installed Xamarin Studio today, and my current Android SDK Tools is 23.0.5 ... I had the same problem, but down grading to 23.0.2 resolved it for me as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution is here: http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/51784/#Comment_51784
Only this time, you need to downgrade from 23.0.4 to 23.0.2.
Just found this out the hard way.

Cheers

Comment: Please refrain from givinf link-only answers. When this link rots, your answer will not be of any use. Instead, try to include the solution in your answer, along with the source.

Comment: +1 This link is still better than anything they provide on their forums in terms of support lol.

Comment: Bad time to try Xamarin for the first time, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Balint!   You made my weekend!!!   Here is a direct link to the tools version that works.

http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r23.2-windows.zip

Comment: That link is a 404.  I think you meant to link http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r23.0.2-windows.zip

Answer (score 0):

I recently had this same issue when trying to open the main.xaml in Xamarin Studio for Mac OS X. Here are the steps I took to resolve the problem:

1. Open the Android SDK Manager in Xamarin Studio and delete the Android SDK Tools.
2. Re-download the SDK Tools from [https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html?hl=i]. Revision 23.0.2
3. Make sure the downloaded SDK is unzipped in the path /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-macosx
4. Then I launched the SDK Manager from the Terminal using cd library/developer/xamarin/android-sdk-macosx/tools ./android
5. When the SDK launches, make sure the Android SDK Tools is not selected, else it will update it to 23.0.5 which appears to currently be broken.
6. After the SDK Manager updates and installs all the packages, re-open Xamarin Studio and go to Preferences -> SDK Locations -> Android and chose the path for the Android SDK.

After following these steps I was able to successfully open the main.xaml files for Android on OS X.